# ERPNext Unable to switch back to site erpnext

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I was experimenting on creating new apps with frappe. At some stage after creating the site, I had to switch the default site using `bench use library`. Now I want to switch back to erpnext (the default app). But it's not working when I run: `bench use erpnext` or `bench use erp-next` or `bench use erp_next`. What's the site name to the default erpnext site. Or is there some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The current site name is in `sites/currentsite.txt` of your bench folder.

Comment: But the currentsite is not what I want. The text file only contains the name of the current site which is library_management. What I want to know is the name of the default erpnext site which I want to switch back to.

Comment: The current site is the default site

Answer (score 0):

Go To sites folder- check the site name and use that name **bench use your-site-name**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can run this from the `bench` directory.

`ls  -F sites/`

[image]

there all of the items that are end with `/` except `assets/` are your sites.

so you can use any site like this `bench use [siteNameExcept/]`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The default site when you use the easy install script is always `site1.local`

So, you can switch to the default using:

```
bench use site1.local
```